# Does Mule FunctionalTestCase needs org.junit.rules.TestRule class to run

Tags: java, junit, junit4, mule, junit-rule

I'm trying to run a simple `Functional test` in Mule 3.3. Below is my sample code:

```
import java.util.Map;    
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.client.MuleClient;
import org.mule.tck.junit4.FunctionalTestCase;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class SoapServiceTest extends FunctionalTestCase {

    @Override
    protected String getConfigResources() {
        return "mule-config.xml,core-config.xml";
    }       

    @Test
    public void testSend() throws Exception
    {
        MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
        String payload = "foo";
        Map<String, Object> properties = null;
        MuleMessage result = client.send("http://localhost:61005/service", payload, properties);
        assertNotNull(result.getPayloadAsString());
    }    
}
```

But it complains `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/rules/TestRule`. I've `junit4.8.1.jar` in my classpath but that doesn't have `TestRule` class which guess is `junit4.9` onwards.

Does Mule needs this class? I'm not using any of the annotations of `TestRule`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Mule's parent POM](http://svn.codehaus.org/mule/tags/mule-3.3.1/pom.xml):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.9</version>
</dependency>
```

So yes, Mule relies on JUnit 4.9, whether you depend on it directly or not.

When you add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

to your project's POM, JUnit 4.9 should be pulled in for you.

Comment: Thanks David for your response and pom link. My project is using `Mule 3.3.0` and I have the above mentioned dependency in my project pom but also separate dependency defined for `junit4.8.1`. Why do we need to define a separate dependency for junit when mule can pull it up. I see same trend in this sample [pom](https://github.com/ddossot/mule-in-action-2e/blob/master/chapter01/pom.xml), though this defines `junit4.9`

Comment: You don't need to add JUnit in the POM if you add `mule-tests-functional`. It's an oversight of us to have added it in chapter 1's POM you're pointing to. I've removed it.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation. Wish I could upvote more than once